# Set "to" field on email form i dynamics 365

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics

I am trying to open a new email form in Dynamics 365 using JavaScript. I can easily pre-fill various fields like "Regarding" but when I try to fill the "To" field it just comes out empty.

Here is a small code snippet reproducing my problem:

```js
let contactid = "91be7fec-2142-ec11-8c62-000d3ac23084";
let activityParameters = {};

// Set the regarding field -- this works!
activityParameters["regardingobjectid"] = contactid ;
activityParameters["regardingobjectidname"] = "Regarding your last email";
activityParameters["regardingobjectidtype"] = "contact";

// Set the to field -- this is not working!
var parties = [];
var receiver = {};
receiver["partyid_contact@odata.bind"] = `/contacts(${contactid})`;
receiver["participationtypemask"] = 2; //To
parties.push(receiver);
activityParameters["email_activity_parties"] = parties;
        
await window.parent.Xrm.Navigation.navigateTo(
            { pageType: "entityrecord", entityName: "email", data: activityParameters },
            { target: 2 } // Open in modal
        )
```

I have also tried some variations based on how lookups are set in other places, like:

```js
var parties = [];
var receiver = {
    activityparty: {
        id: contactid,
        entityType: "contact",
        name: "XXX"
    },
    participationtypemask: 2
};
```

Googling the problem only gave me solutions for creating emails using the web API (as I have tried above), but I am unsure how to change the code so that `navigateTo()` recognizes the parameter.

Does anyone have an idea how to go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured it out. [Andrew Butenko](https://butenko.pro/2020/04/17/populate-regarding-and-activity-party-fields-in-the-uci-interface/) described how to do it for `openForm()`, and it turns out the same solution can also be applied to `navigateTo()`.

I'll leave my solution here in case anyone else has the same problem.

```js
let contactid = "91be7fec-2142-ec11-8c62-000d3ac23084";
let activityParameters = {};
​
// Set the to field -- this IS working!
activityParameters["to"] = [{
    id: contactid,
    name: "Contact Name Here",
    entityType: "contact"
}];
      
await window.parent.Xrm.Navigation.navigateTo(
            { pageType: "entityrecord", entityName: "email", data: activityParameters },
            { target: 2 } // Open in modal
        );
```